# The add and delete only affect the table not the list what should I do to make it affect the list

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist, tableview, scenebuilder

So, I have added and delete function in the DocTableController to edit the table in the GUI. I link the ArrayList from main controller to DocTableController.
When I delete and add the item it appears to be effective only on to the table but not the list once I back to the main menu and back to the DocTable scene again the list reinitialise. and doesn't change when I go into the tableView again.

**main controller**

```
public class FXMLdocumentController implements Initializable {
    @FXML Label date;
    @FXML Label time;
        
    //define static so in memory only 1 list
    static ArrayList<Doctor> doctor = new ArrayList<Doctor>();
    static int counter = 0;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        //initialise all the list
        if (counter == 0){
            doctor.add(new Doctor("518", "Lew Wei Li", "Surgeon", "10PM-3AM", "MBBS,MD","Male",8000 , 88));
            doctor.add(new Doctor("101", "Tom Wong", "Obstetrician", "8AM-11AM", "MBBS,MS","Male",10000 ,11));
            doctor.add(new Doctor("102", "John Lim", "Physician", "7AM-11AM", "MBBS,MS","Male",7000 ,45));
            doctor.add(new Doctor("103", "Amy Chia", "Pediatrician", "6PM-11PM", "MBBS,MD","Female",6000, 8));
            doctor.add(new Doctor("104", "Chris Hemsworth", "Neurologist", "6PM-11PM", "BDM", "Female",8000,12));
            counter++;
        }
        
        //when the program start get the local computer time and date and display
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        date.setText("Date: " + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/"
                + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        time.setText("Time: " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
                + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    }
    

    
    @FXML
    public void changeScreenDoc(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {//change to doctor session scene
        FXMLLoader loader  = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/Gui/DocTable.fxml"));//get the DocTable gui file
        Parent DocParent = loader.load();
        Scene DocScene = new Scene(DocParent);
        
        //get the data to link to other controller
        DocTablecontroller controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setDoc(doctor);
        
        Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(DocScene);
        window.show();
    }

}
```

**Doctable scene controller**

```
public class DocTablecontroller implements Initializable {
    //configure table
    @FXML private TableView<Doctor> Doctable;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Doctor, String> Idcol;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Doctor, String> Namecol;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Doctor, String> Speccol;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Doctor, String> Worktimecol;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Doctor, String> Quacol;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Doctor, Integer> RoomNumbercol;
    
    //Instance variable to create object
    @FXML private TextField newId;
    @FXML private TextField newName;
    @FXML private TextField newSpecialist;
    @FXML private TextField newWorktime;
    @FXML private TextField newQual;
    @FXML private TextField newRnum;
    
    //for alert user usage
    Alert a = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING); 
    
    //link the data from main controller
    public void setDoc(ArrayList<Doctor> doclist)
    {
        Doctable.getItems().addAll(doclist);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        
        //setting up the table and tell it where to find the value in the class by ("xx")
        Idcol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Doctor,String>("id"));
        Namecol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Doctor,String>("name"));
        Speccol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Doctor,String>("specialist"));
        Worktimecol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Doctor,String>("workTime"));
        Quacol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Doctor,String>("qualification"));
        RoomNumbercol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Doctor,Integer>("roomNum"));
        
        //Doctable.setItems(Doclist);//injecting the observable list to the table 
        
        //set the table cell to be editable
        Doctable.setEditable(true);
        Idcol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        Namecol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        Speccol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        Worktimecol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        Quacol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        RoomNumbercol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void newDoctor() {//add new data(row) in the table(add button)
        Doctor newDoctor = new Doctor();
        boolean flag = true;
        //format checking
        if (!(newDoctor.setId(newId.getText()))){
             newId.setText("Wrong format");
             flag = false;
        }
        if (!(newDoctor.setName(newName.getText()))){
             newName.setText("Wrong format");
        }
        if (!(newDoctor.setSpecialist(newSpecialist.getText()))){
             newSpecialist.setText("Wrong format");
             flag = false;
        }
        if (!(newDoctor.setWorkTime(newWorktime.getText()))){
             newWorktime.setText("Wrong format");
             flag = false;
        }
        if (!(newDoctor.setQualification(newQual.getText()))){
             newQual.setText("Wrong format");
             flag = false;
        }
        if (!(newDoctor.setRoomNum(newRnum.getText()))){
             newRnum.setText("Wrong format");
             flag = false;
        }
        //if the format all correct allow to add new input else alert user some input format is wrong
        if(flag)
        {
            Doctable.getItems().add(newDoctor);
            
        }
        else 
        {
            a.setTitle("Input alert");
            a.setContentText("Input format wrong! please check again");
            a.showAndWait();
        }
    }
    
    //edit cell when a cell is double clicked
    public void changeCellEvent(CellEditEvent<?, ?> edittedcell)
    {
        //get the selected doctor data
        Doctor docSeleted = Doctable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        //gone through format checking
        if(!(docSeleted.setId(edittedcell.getNewValue().toString())))
        {
            //alert if pattern not match
            a.setTitle("Input alert");
            a.setContentText("Input format wrong! please check again");
            a.showAndWait();
        }
        Doctable.refresh();//if no this then the value of edited row will stay as the user input string 
    }
    
    
    //delete user selected cell
    public void dlt() {
            Doctable.getItems().removeAll(Doctable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
    }
    
    
    @FXML//change scene(main menu button)
    public void BackMenu(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader  = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/Gui/Menu.fxml"));
        Parent MenuParent = loader.load();
        
        Scene MenuScene = new Scene(MenuParent);
        
        Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(MenuScene);
        window.show();
    }

    
}
```

The add and delete does affect the table in the GUI
and using edit function to edit the cell it does stay when I go main menu and go back to DocTable
I dont understand why add and delete doesnt work, I am guesing that it affect the table but not the list
How to make the function to affect the list?

Comment: [mcve] please .. mind the __M__ (nobody wants to wade through tons of unrelated code, strip it down to just demonstrate what's not working as expected - must include fxml as well as controller and boilderplate app). Also, learn from the comments to your previous questions, in particular, learn java naming conventions and stick to them!

Comment: some notes: don't use static scope (it's nearly always _not_ what you want), don't use the old Calendar classes .. and read the api doc of classes you use _guesing that it affect the table but not the list_ is correct, but nothing to guess :)

Answer (score 0):

When you add or delete a doctor you work with the `ObservableList` of the `TableView` (not with the `ArrayList`). With some changes it should work. Please try this:

Change `ArrayList` in **FxmlDocumentController** to this:

```
ObservableList<Doctor> doctors = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

In the **DocTableController** the setter method can look like this:

```
public void setDoc(ObservableList<Doctor> docList) {
    docTable.getItems().setAll(docList);
}
```

Btw.: Please have a look at the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). ;-)

Comment: unrelated: this mixture of bolding and code tags (for single works) is .. terrible for the reading flow, IMO. No need for either (code tags for key words/class names are controversial, though, I'm fighting a lost battle :))

Comment: @kleopatra so first of all thanks for the advice and I am only learning this for only a couple week and  this assignment is due in 1 week time but teacher teach nothing about it. and i Dono why you sound so angry and i apologise for your inconvenient, sorry i know it was my bad i will try to learn java naming convention but at my current time i really just trying to do my  best and find as much as i could

Comment: @anko i know this work but my assignment limit  us to use arraylist haha so thanks anyway

Comment: @javafxnewbie whenever you publish code (aka: ask questions with code), you communicate. Make that communication as simple as possible by sticking to (java naming) conventions is in your own interest: without, people might not bother to even read your stuff as it's looks like you didn't invest any effort into making the communication smooth.